# How to solve this differential equation of second order?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution to this second order differential equation:
$$(1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}-2x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-2y=0 \, .$$

My try:

i know Particular integral is zero, so complementary function is to be found out,

i solved for $D\equiv \mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$ as $$D=\frac{-(-2x)\pm\sqrt{(-2x)^2-4(1-x^2)(-2)}}{2(1-x^2)}=\frac{x\pm\sqrt{2-x^2}}{1-x^2}$$

i really don't if i am correct or not. someone please help to solve this by some other method like power series solution or some other easy method. thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this helps or not but notice that the $(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2x\frac{dy}{dx}$ can be expressed as $\frac{d((1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx})}{dx}$

Comment: The solutions are Legendre's polynomials.

Comment: @Artem. With complex arguments moreover.

Comment: I suspect that the equation is wrong. It could be $\left(1-x^2\right) y''+2 x y'-2 y=0$ or $\left(1-x^2\right) y''-2 x y'+2 y=0$ instead. Could you check ?

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is a Legendre differential equations which has the general form
$$
(1-x^2) \, y'' - 2x y' + \alpha(1+\alpha)y = 0 \, ,
$$
which it can also be written as 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( (1-x^2) \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right) + \alpha(1+\alpha)y = 0 \ .
$$

Therefore the solution for $\alpha(1+\alpha)=-2$ reads
$$
y(x)= c_1 P_\alpha (x) + c_2 Q_\alpha (x) \, , 
$$ 
wherein $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$ and $P$ and $Q$ are the Legendre and associated Legendre polynomials respectively.

I was wondering whether a more compact expression can be obtained.

Hope this could help a bit.

Federiko